# Run javascript for X amount of minutes

Tags: javascript

i am trying to create a program that will run for X amount of minutes.

minutes was always set to 1 in testing

```
 var minutes = $('#minutes').val();
 var runtime = minutes*60; // gets the seconds
 var secondsEpoch = new Date() / 1000; // Epoch time
 var End = secondsEpoch + runtime; // add the minutes to the current epoch

if (secondsEpoch < End) {
    window.setInterval(RunClock, 1000/10);
} else {
   clearInterval(RunClock);
}

function RunClock() {
    console.log(new Date() / 1000);
    //my code
}
```

The script runs for infinity and i'm confused on why ???

When alerting variable secondsEpoch and End i always end up with a time difference of 1 minute?

Alerted the start and finish times and got

```
Start 1395022190.621
Finish 1395022250.621
```

Total difference of 60 which = 1 minute
but the console log at this minute is

```
1395022456.657
```

which is obviously greater than

```
1395022250.621
```

and the scrip is still running and not stopping

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing your interval correctly. This way it will work:

```
var interval;

if (secondsEpoch < End) {
    interval = setInterval(RunClock, 1000/10);
} else {
   clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: Still wont work ?? whilst typing this the start time is 1395023257.488 and finish time is 1395023287.488 and console log is at 1395023315.324 ??